# SQL ORACLE ERROR PLS-00386: los tipos no coinciden en 'CURTOTALF' entre cursor FETCH y variables INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy tratando de hacer un procedimiento almacenado para realizar una pequeña facturacion, pero me marca el siguiente error al recuperar los tipos de datos en el cursor,
la consulta es funcional y la recuperacion del tipo de dato la hice con %TYPE por lo que no se porque marca este error:
**ERROR PLS-00386: los tipos no coinciden en 'CURTOTALF' entre cursor FETCH y variables INTO**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  
    procFacturacion   
    (procIdVentFac IN VENTA.id_ventas%TYPE) IS     
    CURSOR CursorFactura IS --DECLARACION DEL CURSOR   
    SELECT TIENDA.id_tie, TIENDA.calle_t,TIENDA.cp_t,TIENDA.nexterior_t,TIENDA.colonia_t,   
    VENTA.cantidad_v, FACTURA_CLIENTE.total_fac,  
    FACTURA_CLIENTE.fecha_fac, FACTURA_CLIENTE.hora_fac    
    ,PRODUCTO.precio_p,PRODUCTO.titulo, PRODUCTO.producto_id,  
    CLIENTE.nombre_c, CLIENTE.apellido_c, CLIENTE.telefono_c    
    FROM VENTA, PRODUCTO, FACTURA_CLIENTE, CLIENTE, TIENDA   
    WHERE VENTA.id_ventas= procIdVentFac AND VENTA.prod_v=PRODUCTO.producto_id   
    AND FACTURA_CLIENTE.id_facclie=VENTA.facven AND TIENDA.id_tie= PRODUCTO.tien_p   
    AND CLIENTE.rfcclie =  FACTURA_CLIENTE.facrfc;  
    curId_tie       TIENDA.id_tie%TYPE;  
    curCalle_t      TIENDA.calle_t%TYPE;  
    curCp_t         TIENDA.cp_t%TYPE;  
    curNexterior_t  TIENDA.nexterior_t%TYPE;  
    curColonia_t    TIENDA.colonia_t%TYPE;  
    curCANTIDAD     VENTA.cantidad_v%TYPE;      
    curTotalf       FACTURA_CLIENTE.total_fac%TYPE;     
    curVFECHA       FACTURA_CLIENTE.fecha_fac%TYPE;                     
    curVHORA        FACTURA_CLIENTE.hora_fac%TYPE;   
    curPrecio_p     PRODUCTO.precio_p%TYPE;  
    curTitulo       PRODUCTO.titulo%TYPE;  
    curProducto_id  PRODUCTO.producto_id%TYPE;  
    curNombre_c     CLIENTE.nombre_c%TYPE;  
    curApellido_c   CLIENTE.apellido_c%TYPE;  
    curTelefono_c   CLIENTE.telefono_c%TYPE;  
BEGIN   
    OPEN CursorFactura;   
    LOOP  
    FETCH CursorFactura   
        INTO      
            curId_tie, curId_tie,     
            curCalle_t, curCp_t,   
            curNexterior_t, curColonia_t,  
            curCANTIDAD, curTotalf,  
            curVFECHA, curVHORA,  
            curprecio_p, curtitulo, curproducto_id,  
            curNombre_c, curApellido_c,   
            curTelefono_c;      
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------FACTURA----'||curId_tie||'--------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FACTURAR A:------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( curNombre_c||' '||curApellido_c||' '||curTelefono_c||'-----');     
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FECHA DE FACTURACION: '||curVFECHA||'  HORA: '||curVHORA);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ---------------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(curCalle_t||' '||curCp_t||'---------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(curNexterior_t||' '||curColonia_t||'------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' --------------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CANTIDAD   ID PRODUCTO    PRODUCTO DESCRIPCION   PRECIO   ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(curCANTIDAD||''||curproducto_id||' ' ||curtitulo||' '||curprecio_p  );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------------------TOTAL PAGADO--'||curTotalf||'-');  
        EXIT WHEN CursorFactura%NOTFOUND;  
    END LOOP;  
    CLOSE CursorFactura;  
END;  
/
```

Comment: `FACTURA_CLIENTE.total_fac` está en la posición 7 del cursor, `curTotalf` está en la posición 8 del fetch. Seguro los tipos de columna no van a coincidir

Comment: Gracias! no lo habia notado!